# Repetitions in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Following is mysql query, I'm hoping to repeat data in the result. I've tried UNION ALL , but it throws a syntax error.

```
Select attribute_name from attribute WHERE (SELECT attribute_id from platform_metadata_map );
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Show sample data and desired result. That `where` clause is meaningless and so provides no indication of what you're actually trying to achieve. Also show what you tried with `union all` and any other things you've tried that didn't work. People need to know what you're trying to do and what's failed so that they can correct where required.

Comment: I think you need to show us the tables to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong beacuse

```
Select attribute_name 
from attribute 
WHERE (SELECT attribute_id from platform_metadata_map );
```

the where clause don't match   (you shoudl use where attribute_id = (select ....))
anyway  you want repeat you should repet  teh query using union all

```
Select attribute_name 
from attribute 
union all 
Select attribute_name 
from attribute 
union all
Select attribute_name 
from attribute 
union all 
Select attribute_name 
from attribute
```